# NotificationCenter Widget Failed To Use CoreLocation

Tags: ios, widget, core-location, jailbreak

I'm writing a notification center widget, and it had to use location information. In normal apps I use CoreLocation and it works fine. But in my widget, I tried to `locationServicesEnabled` but it didn't go to the callback functions, and the `authorizationStatus` is always `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, and the authorize setting didn't show up in **Setting -> location service**. I already set the delegate to the class.

The system's Yahoo weather widget can auto locating and it uses CoreLocation too, so the widget do have ability to use location service.

**Why CoreLocation doesn't work on my widget?**

---

**Update: 2012.10.24 15:52**

I use private API

```objc
[CLLocationManager setAuthorizationStatus:YES 
                                forBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]]
```

Now, the authorize setting shows in the Setting->location service. And every time I pull down the notification center, it turns on. But the `authorizationStatus`is still `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` and won't go to the callback functions.

---

**Update: 2012.10.25 10:38**

I change my locating code to:

```objc
[CLLocationManager setDefaultEffectiveBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]];
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

If I turn off location service, it will jump to

```objc
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

If I turn the service on, no matter I authorize it or not, there's no calling back (both

```objc
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

and

```objc
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

won't be invoked).

By the way, when I turn on/off the service,

```objc
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

will be invoked, but not when I change the authorizationStatus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because a WeeAppPlugin bundle is not a effective bundle that cause the widget cant's use location service. After I user `[[CLLocationManager alloc] initWithEffectiveBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class]]` in private API of CoreLocation, the widget can get location info normally.